# How to get billing address from sales/order_grid_collection?

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, sales-order, sales, order-grid

I have `sales/order_grid_collection`

where I'm getting the desired attributes on my grid, but the last one attribute I need is the **billing street of the order**, how can I get that programmatically?

Here is my code:

```
public function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_grid_collection')->addAttributeToSelect('*');

    $this->setCollection($collection);
    parent::_prepareCollection();
}

protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumn('real_order_id', array(
        'header' => $this->_getHelper()->__('#'),
        'width' => '80px',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'index' => 'increment_id'
    ));
    $this->addColumn('created_at', array(
        'header' => $this->_getHelper()->__('Date'),
        'index' => 'created_at',
        'type' => 'datetime',
        'width' => '100px'
    ));
    $this->addColumn('billing_name', array(
        'header' => $this->_getHelper()->__('Customer'),
        'index' => 'billing_name'
    ));
    // THIS IS THE ATTRIBUTE I NEED TO SHOW:
    $this->addColumn('billing_street', array(
        'header' => $this->_getHelper()->__('Address'),
        'index' => 'billing_street'
    ));
    //--------------------------------------------------
    $this->addColumn('status', array(
        'header' => $this->_getHelper()->__('Status'),
        'index' => 'status',
        'type'  => 'options',
        'width' => '70px',
        'options' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getStatuses()
    ));

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join the table **sales_flat_order_address**, to get the billing information.

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
    $collection->getSelect()
                ->join(array('address' => $collection->getTable("sales/order_address")), 
                    'main_table.entity_id = address.parent_id AND address.address_type = "billing"'
                    )
                ->columns('address.street as billing_street');
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```